# How to get results from 2 conditions

Tags: excel

I have 4 columns. Column one is list of unique IDs, column 2 empty, column 3 is list of ids but there can be duplicates in it and column 4 has some text. Can I write some formula in column 2 that would check if the ID in column 1 is present in column 3 and for each time its present check if the text in the cell next to in in column 4 contains "hey" in it. If it does this text should be returned in column 2.

```
1       1   hey whatever
2       1   whatever
4       3   whatever
6       3   hey maybe
        3   maybe
        4   hey whatever maybe
        5   whatever maybe
        5   hey whatever
```

Maybe I'm over-complicating things, but I cant think of a way to break down the problem. Thanks in advance for any tips.

For this example the result should be:

```
1   hey whatever        1   hey whatever
2   N/a                 1   whatever
4   hey whatever maybe  3   whatever
6   N/a                 3   hey maybe
                        3   maybe
                        4   hey whatever maybe
                        5   whatever maybe
                        5   hey whatever
```

EDIT: The solution in the linked topic supposes that the values are given from the start and and it looks for exact line matches on a line here I think we need a formula that that cycles through the results of another formula until it finds a match.

Comment: I see that my question is similar to the other topic, but its different enough that the solutions suggested there do not work for this problem. Please remove the "marked as duplicate".

Comment: There are two answers listed above, try putting the two together and come back with what you have tried.  The answer is there.